# Red5 save multiple audio streams as single file

Tags: java, red5

I am using Red5 1.0.6

There is a conference between three clients. 3 clients open different stream from their end. By using saveAs I can save then into individual files. Is it possible to save all the three stream in a single file?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will possible since a recorded FLV file only uses a "stream id" of 0. What you'd really want is one stream id per audio (track). Even if you wrote a recorder yourself, nothing out there would know how to play it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention three stream already on RED5. using G streamer pull all three stream from RED5 and mux it, Then again publish final stream on RED5.

```
    ]-->   Stream1 --> [             ]
RED5|-->   Stream2 --> |  G streamer |--> Mux --> [FinalStream] --> [Red5]
    ]-->   Stream3 --> [             ]
```

write pipeline for muxing and save that final stream using saveAs method (contain 3 video) in single file.